Missing a $\pi$ when using definite integral to find torus volume
I encountered a problem in the "Use definite integral to find volume" chapter that told me to calculate the volume of half a torus with the major radius of 8 cm and the minor radius of 1 cm.
So, after some visualization, I came up with this integral using the definition of "find the volume using definite integral when knowing formula to calculate the area of thin slices of the object"
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1{(9 - |x|)^2 - (7 + |x|)^2}
\end{align*}
$$
Actually, the absolute value is quite redundant because in my visualization, I'm progressing inward from -1 to 0. I'm progressing in the direction perpendicular to the plane containing the coplanar circular axis of the torus (apologies for the lack of vocabulary... don't know what to call that surface). So, $sliceArea = \pi\times(tubeLargeRadiusAtX^2 - tubeSmallRadiusAtX^2)$
Which, after plugged into the calculator seems to produce the correct answer. Except for the fact that it's missing 1 $\pi$ (The answer is $8\pi^2$).
To confirm my answer, I used the normal formula to calculate a torus' volume and divide it by 2 $\pi(majorRadius)\times\pi(minorRadius)^2$ also results in the same answer, with $\pi^2$.
Could anyone explain why is that? Where's the missing $\pi$? Am I using the integral formula incorrectly?

I would also calculate the volume using Pappus's Centroid Theorem approach and see if that helps you develop any insight.
